# SQL column with calculate default value while creating table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a table with two columns, **holiday_date** and **day_of_the_week**.

I'd like the **day_of_the_week** column to be derived by default from the **holiday_date** column using the **datepart()** function.
The **day_of_the_week** column is by default null and computed when new values of **holiday_date** are inserted.

I have tried using the query below:

```
CREATE TABLE [HolidaysTest] (
    [holiday_date] varchar(50),
    [day_of_the_week] int DEFAULT datepart(dW, holiday_date)
)
```

This isn't working and the error that results is shown below

> The name "holiday_date" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

Comment: Use a computed column? You don't want to edit it do you?

Comment: No I don't. I'd like it to return an integer value representing the day of the week depending on the date.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `day_of_the_week()` to be in the table and always consistent with `holiday_date`, then I would recommend:

```
create table HolidaysTest (
    holiday_date date,
    day_of_the_week as (datepart(weekday, holiday_date))
);
```

Note the change of type of `holiday_date`.  *Do not store dates as strings!*  Use the built-in data types.

`day_of_the_week` is calculated when you refer to it in a query.  It is always accurate.

Also not that `weekday` is spelled out.  This generally makes queries less ambiguous and more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to store day of week and you only want to return `int` value representing week of day then don't create column for it in table.

Just create your table with `holiday_date` and at time of fire select query 
write something like this:

```
select holiday_date, DATEPART(WEEKDAY, holiday_date) from HolidaysTest
```